# Let $ X \sim e(\lambda)$ prove that $ \lfloor X \rfloor $ is geometrically distributed.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $ X \sim e(\lambda)$ prove  that  $ \lfloor X \rfloor $ is geometrically distributed.

Here is what I have done:
$ P(\lfloor X \rfloor\le t)= P(X\le t)$.    (1)
$ = 1-e^{-\lambda(t+1)} $ .   (2)
$= 1-(e^{-\lambda})^{t+1}$   (3)
Therefore $\lfloor X \rfloor \sim G(1-e^{-\lambda})$

Is this sufficient? This is not an assignment question, just a problem sheet question, so I am allowed to solicit help online. In line 3, t is still a continuous number, whereas in the geometric distribution, t has to be discrete, so is the way I have done it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is ok since you could restrict $t$ to be any integer (but it should be understood that your equation $1$ is only true if $t$ is an integer). The tricky thing is that CDFs of discrete distributions are annoying since they jump. So really what's written as the CDF is actually the CDF restricted to the atoms of the distribution (the integers in this case). For this reason it might be better to compute the pmf, which doesn't have this potential for confusion and is how I'm used to seeing the geometric distribution expressed anyway.

We have $$ P( \lfloor X\rfloor =n) = P(X < n+1) - P(X<n) = (1-e^{-\lambda(n+1)}) -(1-e^{-\lambda n}) = e^{-\lambda n}(1-e^{-\lambda})$$ which is the pmf of a geometric with $p= (1-e^{-\lambda}).$